# OpenMP segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, openmp

recently I am working on a c OpenMP code which carrying out the affinity scheduling. Basically, after a thread has finished its assigned iterations, it will start looking for other threads which has the most work load and steal some jobs from them.

Everything works fine, I can compile the file using icc. However, when I try to run it, it gives me the segmentation fault(core dumped). But the funny thing is, the error is not always happen, that is, even I get an error when I first run the code, when I try to run again, sometimes it works. This is so weird to me. I wonder what I did wrong in my code and how to fix the problem. Thank you. I did only modified the method runloop and affinity, others are given at the beginning which works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


#define N 729
#define reps 1000 
#include <omp.h> 


double a[N][N], b[N][N], c[N];
int jmax[N];  


void init1(void);
void init2(void);
void runloop(int); 
void loop1chunk(int, int);
void loop2chunk(int, int);
void valid1(void);
void valid2(void);
int affinity(int*, int*, int, int, float, int*, int*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 

    double start1,start2,end1,end2;
    int r;

  init1(); 

  start1 = omp_get_wtime(); 

  for (r=0; r<reps; r++){ 
    runloop(1);
  } 

  end1  = omp_get_wtime();  

  valid1(); 

  printf("Total time for %d reps of loop 1 = %f\n",reps, (float)(end1-start1)); 


  init2(); 

  start2 = omp_get_wtime(); 

  for (r=0; r<reps; r++){ 
    runloop(2);
  } 

  end2  = omp_get_wtime(); 

  valid2(); 

  printf("Total time for %d reps of loop 2 = %f\n",reps, (float)(end2-start2)); 

} 

void init1(void){
  int i,j; 

  for (i=0; i<N; i++){ 
    for (j=0; j<N; j++){ 
      a[i][j] = 0.0; 
      b[i][j] = 3.142*(i+j); 
    }
  }

}

void init2(void){ 
  int i,j, expr; 

  for (i=0; i<N; i++){ 
    expr =  i%( 3*(i/30) + 1); 
    if ( expr == 0) { 
      jmax[i] = N;
    }
    else {
      jmax[i] = 1; 
    }
    c[i] = 0.0;
  }

  for (i=0; i<N; i++){ 
    for (j=0; j<N; j++){ 
      b[i][j] = (double) (i*j+1) / (double) (N*N); 
    }
  }

}  


void runloop(int loopid)
{
  int nthreads = omp_get_max_threads(); // we set it before the parallel region, using opm_get_num_threads() will always return 1 otherwise                             
    int ipt = (int) ceil((double)N/(double)nthreads);           
    float chunks_fraction = 1.0 / nthreads;                                 
    int threads_lo_bound[nthreads];                                         
    int threads_hi_bound[nthreads];                                     

    #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(threads_lo_bound, threads_hi_bound, nthreads, loopid, ipt, chunks_fraction)
    {
        int myid = omp_get_thread_num();
        int lo = myid * ipt;
    int hi = (myid+1)*ipt;
    if (hi > N) hi = N; 

        threads_lo_bound[myid] = lo;
        threads_hi_bound[myid] = hi;

        int current_lower_bound = 0;
        int current_higher_bound = 0;
        int affinity_steal = 0;

        while(affinity_steal != -1)
        {
            switch(loopid)
            {
                case 1: loop1chunk(current_lower_bound, current_higher_bound); break;
                case 2: loop2chunk(current_lower_bound, current_higher_bound); break;
            }

            #pragma omp critical
            {
                affinity_steal = affinity(threads_lo_bound, threads_hi_bound, nthreads, myid, chunks_fraction, &current_lower_bound, &current_higher_bound);
            }
        }
    }
}

int affinity(int* threads_lo_bound, int* threads_hi_bound, int num_of_thread, int thread_num, float chunks_fraction, int *current_lower_bound, int *current_higher_bound)
{
    int current_pos;

    if (threads_hi_bound[thread_num] - threads_lo_bound[thread_num] > 0)
    {
        current_pos = thread_num;
    }
    else
    {
        int new_pos = -1;
        int jobs_remain = 0;
    int i;
        for (i = 0; i < num_of_thread; i++)
        {
            int diff = threads_hi_bound[i] - threads_lo_bound[i];
            if (diff > jobs_remain)
            {
                new_pos = i;
                jobs_remain = diff;
            }
        }

        current_pos = new_pos;
    }

    if (current_pos == -1) return -1;

    int remaining_iterations = threads_hi_bound[current_pos] - threads_lo_bound[current_pos];
    int iter_size_fractions = (int)ceil(chunks_fraction * remaining_iterations);

    *current_lower_bound = threads_lo_bound[current_pos];
    *current_higher_bound = threads_lo_bound[current_pos] + iter_size_fractions;
    threads_lo_bound[current_pos] = threads_lo_bound[current_pos] + iter_size_fractions;

    return current_pos;
}

void loop1chunk(int lo, int hi) { 
  int i,j; 

  for (i=lo; i<hi; i++){ 
    for (j=N-1; j>i; j--){
      a[i][j] += cos(b[i][j]);
    } 
  }

} 


void loop2chunk(int lo, int hi) {
  int i,j,k; 
  double rN2; 

  rN2 = 1.0 / (double) (N*N);  

  for (i=lo; i<hi; i++){ 
    for (j=0; j < jmax[i]; j++){
      for (k=0; k<j; k++){ 
    c[i] += (k+1) * log (b[i][j]) * rN2;
      } 
    }
  }

}

void valid1(void) { 
  int i,j; 
  double suma; 

  suma= 0.0; 
  for (i=0; i<N; i++){ 
    for (j=0; j<N; j++){ 
      suma += a[i][j];
    }
  }
  printf("Loop 1 check: Sum of a is %lf\n", suma);

} 


void valid2(void) { 
  int i; 
  double sumc; 

  sumc= 0.0; 
  for (i=0; i<N; i++){ 
    sumc += c[i];
  }
  printf("Loop 2 check: Sum of c is %f\n", sumc);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't initialise the arrays `threads_lo_bound` and `threads_hi_bound`, so they initially contain some completely random values (this is source of randomness number 1).

You then enter the parallel region, where it is imperative to realise not all threads will be moving through the code in sync, the actual speed of each threads is quite random as it shares the CPU with many other programs, even if they only use 1%, that will still show (this is source of randomness number 2, I'd argue this one is more relevant to why you see it working every now and then).

*So what happens when the code crashes?*

One of the threads (most likely the master) reaches the critical region before at least one of the other threads has reached the line where you set `threads_lo_bound[myid]` and `threads_hi_bound[myid]`.

After that, depending on what those random values stored in there were (you can generally assume they were out of bounds, your array is fairly small, the odds of those values being valid indices are pretty slim), the thread will try to steal some of the jobs (that don't exist) by setting `current_lower_bound` and/or `current_upper_bound` to some value that is out of range of your initial arrays `a, b, c`.

It will then enter the second iteration of your `while(affinity_steal != -1)` loop and access memory that is out of bounds inevitably leading to a segmentation fault (eventually, in principle it's undefined behaviour and the crash can occur at any point after an invalid memory access, or in some cases never, leading you to believe everything is in order, when it is most definitely not).

The fix of course is simple, add

```
#pragma omp barrier
```

just before the `while(affinity_steal != -1)` loop to ensure all threads have reached that point (i.e. synchronise the threads at that point) and the bounds are properly set before you proceed into the loop. The overhead of this is minimal, but if for some reason you wish to avoid using barriers, you can simply set the values of the array before entering the parallel region.

That said, bugs like this can usually be located using a good debugger, I strongly suggest learning how to use one, they make life much easier.

Comment: Thank you so much! It solves the problem. And I will try to learn how to use a proper debugger. Thank you!